# Profiling parameters

Tags: sql-server, profiler

I was trying to fine the parameters of a query I suspect to be causing unnecessary logical read and eventually captured it in profiler, however parameters @p3 and @p4 are not listed.  Is anyone able to explain was SQL server is doing here?

Many thanks

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1073764508
declare @p2 int
set @p2=180527133
declare @p5 int
set @p5=16
declare @p6 int
set @p6=1
declare @p7 int
set @p7=0
exec sp_cursorprepexec @p1 output,@p2 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int',N'SELECT A.POPUP,A.EMAIL,A.CREATEDBY,A.BATCHJOBID,101090,B.EMAIL,B.EVENTPOPUPDISPLAYWHEN,B.EVENTEMAILALERTSWHEN,B.ID,101090,C.LANGUAGE,C.ID,101090,D.RECID,D.STATUS,D.CAPTION,D.COMPANY,D.BATCHJOBID,D.STARTDATETIME,D.STARTDATETIMETZID,D.ENDDATETIME,D.ENDDATETIMETZID,D.ORIGSTARTDATETIME,D.ORIGSTARTDATETIMETZID,D.CANCELEDBY FROM BATCHJOBALERTS A,SYSUSERINFO B,USERINFO C,BATCHJOBHISTORY D WHERE (A.CREATEDBY=B.ID) AND (C.ID=B.ID) AND (((D.ALERTSPROCESSED=@P1) AND (D.BATCHJOBID=A.BATCHJOBID)) AND ((((D.STATUS=@P2) AND (A.BATCHJOBENDED=@P3)) OR ((D.STATUS=@P4) AND (A.BATCHJOBERROR=@P5))) OR ((D.STATUS=@P6) AND (A.BATCHJOBCANCELED=@P7))))',@p5 output,@p6 output,@p7 output,1,4,1,3,1,8,1
select @p1, @p2, @p5, @p6, @p7
```

Comment: I was just wondering if anyone could explain my above question as I still have been unable to explain it?

Answer (score 1):

This is problematic the program is declaring a query whose results will be spooled on the server. The the program will call for one record at a time from the result set. The *literal* variables (p1,p2,p5,p6,p7) should be related to the configuration of the system stored procedure. The *stringed* variables (p1-p7) are represented by the last 7 terms of the procedure call.

```
    exec sp_cursorprepexec 
        @p1 output, -- plan handle for statement after its prepared
        @p2 output, -- cursor, the the program can retrieve one row at a time from the result set
        N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int',--parameters for execution
        N'<<query text params here reference the list above>>', --statement, parameters here are the ones form the string list above
        @p5 output, --
        @p6 output, -- configuration terms see the docs
        @p7 output, -- 
        -- sql server will compile the query with unknown values for @P1 - @P7
        -- these values will be substituted for @P1-@P7 after its compiled
        1, --@P1
        4,
        1,
        3,
        1,
        8,
        1 --@P7
```

docs for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff848775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx